# Timage GIF support missing from delphi 7 after porting code

Tags: delphi

I am porting a large project of code from Delphi 4 to Delphi 7.

For some reason Timage does not seem to have any more GIF file support in delphi 7.

Is there a workaround so that Delphi 7 can load DFM forms that have Gifs there?

Comment: http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/

Comment: Out of interest, why are you upgrading to Delphi 7? It's ancient (although I guess less ancient than Delphi 4 :)) Why not port to XE6, the latest version? If you're going through the hassle of porting you might as well choose to port to the one with the most features. Plus, XE6 has GIF image support built in.

Comment: Thanks David, actually I bought Xe6 license to get delphi7 and all other versions..  Reason is simple: Porting is easier to D7 and I dont need any xe6 features at moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 4 did not have GIF support out of the box; neither did Delphi 7.

There were third-party components that added that support, such as [TGifImage](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/).

If you have a Delphi 4 app that supports GIFs, you'll need to determine which third-party component set added that support and find the Delphi 7 version (or port the Delphi 4 version yourself - with the exception of changes to separate design-time and run-time code, there weren't any breaking changes between those versions).

Comment: I think the most common package for supporting GIFs was the RXLib back in Delphi4.

Comment: @kobik: You might be right. I have trouble with ancient history and components I didn't need at the time. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I have found gifimage.pas v2.2 from my sourcecode folder of project, but for some reason D7 does not use it or something. What needs to be done to activate it?

Comment: got it working with a new gifimage v2.2b  that I loaded from here http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/